# default route propagation under rip - quagga

Tags: linux, networking, router, routing, quagga

How would I propagate a default route under RIP, from a router? The operating system is Ubuntu. Can this be done in Quagga? What would be the command?

I found a solution for a cisco router:

```
Router1#configure terminal 
Enter configuration commands, one per line.  End with CNTL/Z.
Router1(config)#ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 172.25.1.1
Router1(config)#router rip
Router1(config-router)#default-information originate
Router1(config-router)#end
```

How would this work in quagga? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [quagga docs](http://www.quagga.net/docs/docs-info.php#SEC37):

```
RIP command: default-information originate
```

seems you can easily do it.